# Ruby on Rails - Passing a hash as a parameter with link_to_remote Rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, link-to-remote

am working in Rails version 2.3.8
Hash => agent_list = [[5, "val"], [4, "val"], [3, "val"], [1, "val"]]

```
<%= link_to_remote "Click Here", 
        :url => {
        :controller => "controller", 
        :action => "method",
        :id => @p_id,
        :hash_list => hash_list
        },
        :method => 'post' %>
```

The link generated is :

[http://localhost/controller/method/12?hash_list%5B%5D%5B%5D=5&hash_list%5B%5D%5B%5D=val&hash_list%5B%5D%5B%5D=4&hash_list%5B%5D%5B%5D=val&hash_list%5B%5D%5B%5D=3&hash_list%5B%5D%5B%5D=val&hash_list%5B%5D%5B%5D=1&hash_list%5B%5D%5B%5D=val]

Could anyone tell me what is the right way to get something like: 
http://localhost/controller/method/12?hash_list=[hash_list]

so that i can use it as params[:agent_list] in my controller method.

P.S. sorry if its a nooby question.

Answer (score 1):

Create a route in your `routes.rb` to the action, if not already created, then:

```
<%= link_to "Click here", my_route_path(@obj, :hash => { :foo => "bar" }), :remote => true, :method => :post %>
```

untested but should do the trick. If you're supplying `remote: true` then it doesn't really matter what your URL looks like, the hash should reside in `params[:hash]` in your controller.

`link_to_remote` is deprecated in Rails 3+.

Rails 2.3.8:

```
<%= link_to_remote "Click here", :url => my_route_path(@obj, :hash => { :foo => "bar" }), :method => :post %>
```

Comment: hey am working in rails 2.3.8. and i am at a point where i cant upgrade to Rails 3. so can u modify the above accordingly pl? cuz i have tried, but am still missing something.

Answer (score 0):

My `<%= link_to @item_link_name, show_item_path(item: {id: @item.id}) %>`

generates `http://localhost:3000/items/show_item?item%5Bid%5D=XXX`,

what is recognised by controller as `params[:item][:id]`